# Why does saving a .scss file create a .css file in rails 4?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sass

I'm not entirely sure what happened, but all of a sudden anytime I make a change to one of my .scss files in my assets folder, as soon as I save it a .css version is automatically created in my assets directory.

For example, let's say I'm working in some_page.css.scss. I add a few lines of code and hit Cmd + S. Immediately, some_page.css is added to the current directory. This is messy, especially from a version control standpoint because if I decide against a change I still have those "new" files I have to delete, because now I have both a .css and an .scss version for the same page in the same directory.

I can't for the life of me figure out what's going on or why this started all of a sudden. Any ideas?

I'm working in Rails 4 with bootstrap-sass. None of the other devs I'm working with are having this issue, and I just pulled the branch.

Comment: Which editor are you using for editing .scss files? Seems like it has plugin for automatically convert .scss files to .css.

Comment: Sublime Text 2. It's doing the same thing for CoffeeScript files as well, but I don't think it's the code editor. I can't think of anything else it would be other than a gem issue, but I have no idea where to start...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I accidentally had LiveReload (http://livereload.com/) compiling the files for me. I unchecked it and viola!